# Game Programming - Billboard issue in front of 3D object

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine

I'm starting to develop a poc with the main features of a turn-based RPG similar to Breath of Fire 4, a mixture of 3D environment with characters and items such as billboards.

I'm using an orthographic camera with an angle of 30 degrees on the X axis, I did my sprite to act as a billboard with the pivot in the center, the problem occurs when the sprite is nearing a 3D object such as a wall.

Check out the image:

[image]

I had tried the solution leaving the rotation matrix of the billboard "upright", worked well, but of course, depending on the height and angle of the camera toward the billboard it gets kinda flattened, I also changed the pivot to the bottom of the sprite but this problem appears with objects in front of the sprite too. I was thinking that the solution would be to create a fragment shader that relies on the depth texture of some previous pass, I tried to think in how to do it with shaders but I could not figure it out. Could you help me with some article or anything that puts me in the right direction? Thank you.

See what I am trying to achieve [on this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0z-wiRFz9U).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had got the right approach. Use the **upright** matrix, and **scale up Z** of billboards preparing flattened Z by your camera. The Z scaling should be about 1.1547. It is (1 / cos30), which makes billboards look like original size from the camera with the angle of 30 degrees. It seems a tricky way but developers of BoF4 on the video might use the same solution too.

Comment: Dish Why the expression is Zscale = 1/cos((sqrt(3)/2)). What is the math involved?

Comment: It's an issue about a projection of the shape. You can know this through a property of trigonometric functions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions

Comment: Is there any link with a mathematical proof that illustrates this projection issue ? It took me a while to read all the materials and learn about the different trig functions but i could not figure it out yet why to use secant scalar of the unit circle to scale my z axis. I really want to understand it, any help will be appreciated. Thanks!